# registeration check if email exist without checking database

Tags: javascript, php, performance, algorithm, registration

consider I want to make a multiple step registration form with Javascript(e.g. Angular) and I don't want to do some ajax before all steps are completely done.
I've thought may be executing a function in Javascript which take user email as an argument which determine whether email exist in database or not.
but actually I don't want my function to do Ajax call.
consider each time a user is registered in database this algorithm should be updated.

it's a little hard to say but I mean there should be an algorithm which determines an item exists or not without having items. (I know it seems a little silly. but actually its not).

you get all items from database once and with knowing all items you write an algorithm which determines whether an given item exist in database or not without knowing database items.

consider log in process system can determine whether user password is correct or not without knowing user password . system just knows some thing about user password (hash or md5 or ...)

so we can here execute a function on our existing user table and get some values and strings or ... and with these values we can detect whether user email already exist in database or not without knowing all items.

one of the reasons which I'm asking question is performance issues(consider user table with so many records.) and the second reason is just to be fancy :)

Comment: Fetching and hashing all your users for the sake of checking (if that's even feasible) is going to be a performance hit, not scanning a table to check for existence.

Comment: So basically, you want to know if an email address X exists in the DB without checking the DB? Doesn't make sense. Why you don't want to simply check the DB?

Comment: @OfirBaruch yes. exactly want tI o know if an email address X exists in the DB without checking the DB. consider I have a user table with so many records which it takes so long to query to database. and I think it's possible to check whether this email exist in database without query to database but I don't know how.

Comment: While you think it's possible - it's not. On what will the algorithm should based its conclusion? It needs data. Otherwise it's just about "guessing".

Comment: @Nadh I don't want to hash all users I want to make an algorithm which generate some hashes through all users and fter executing this function we can check email existence with this hashes generated. consider this algorithm execute once and then just we use it.

Comment: Well, put your users table in memcached and query memcache to see if the user exists.

Comment: Here's an idea that might save you DB performance time, but not necessarily general performance time. Have a string with the following pattern: `user1@gmail.com,user2@yahoo.com,....` and save it in a text file or in the DB. Anytime a new user registers - update that string. When you want to check if an email already exists just use a `strpos` function.

Comment: @OfirBaruch consider XOR when you have $a = 11 and $b = 01 the result of XOR is 10 and if you XOR $a with result you get 01 which is $b.
I know that this algorithm is not my answer but I'm searching for some thing like this algorithm which solve this issue.

Comment: @Jordan I like your idea and I already knew that but I want to be more fancy :)

Comment: may be I get an string from myalgorithm $a and I do some function with user email and this string and I get a true or false which says user exist in table or not.

Comment: I think you're missing the point. You users need to be stored somewhere. You will have to search the somewhere location in order to see if an object exists. You can't just pull something out of the air. You have to compare the user input with something else and return a 1 or 0 result.

Comment: @Jordan I don't want to pull something out of the air. consider I have function called Fancy(). and when I run this fancy function it do something on my users record and generate a string or ... and then I run another function called Exists() which takes user email and this generated string and return value is true or false.

Comment: Okay, I'm failing to see how that would be any faster or better than running an AJAX call to check if the user is in the table?

Comment: @Jordan thanks . I'm hardly digging whether there is a solution or not ?? :)

Comment: What @Jordan is trying to say is: No.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate a hash from the email address.  Suppose the hash is a 20-bit value (just take the bottom 20 bits of md5 hash, for example).  That means you need a 128K byte table where each bit is either 0 or 1 depending on whether there is an email which hashes to that value.  You can easily check for an email present by generating the hash and looking it up in the table.  A 1 means either the email is used or there is a hash collision.  A 0 guarantees the email was not used at the time the table was generated.  To reduce the chance of a collision, make sure the number of bits in the table is much larger than the number of users.  20 bits gives 1 million hash buckets.

Answer (score 0):

So for every request you are going to build a custom response script containgn your entire dataset and send it back to the client for checking? Leaving aside the integrity problem if you don't check the email address sent back from the client and the need to hash the data to prevent disclosure, this is not going to scale well. It will work really quickly with 10s or even 100s of rows but it won't work for 10s of thousands of rows.